# Update mysql db if value is changed and change another value

Tags: php, mysql

in my database i have a updateinfo with timestamp etc. wich should updated everytime the values has changes/update.

actually i check at first if there has changed value (old) and value (new) only if its, i add the update value with new updateinfos.

Now i ask myself how i can do it easier and faster. Normaly mysql dont update somethink if the value has not changes. But whats about my updateinfos. If i add them mysql will update them everytime. How can i do it that mysql only set the new updateinfos if there is really a changed value?

For Example

```
mysql SET a=1, b=2, Updateinfo='TIMESTAMP+IP'
```

What i looking for is a kind like this

```
mysql SET a=1, b=2, (Updateinfo='Timestamp+IP' ONLY IF a or b has updated)
```

So is there a way to add the field Updateinfo='Timestamp...' to the query if there is a change by one of the SET a=1, b=2?

Hope i could explain what i'm looking for.

Comment: please, format your code with correct syntax

Comment: you mean if `a` or `b` has new data to update than `udateinfo` will update?

Comment: yes but also then set and update the updateinfo

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? It's only a pseudo-code, but you get the idea

```
run_query("UPDATE table SET a=1, b=2");
if(success == run_query){
    run_query("UPDATE table SET Updateinfo='Timestamp+IP' WHERE a=1 AND b=2");
} else {
    //some other things...
}
```

## Revise #1

```
$a = 'somevalue';
$b = 'somevalue2';

$result = fetch -> run_query('SELECT a, b FROM table');
$existingA = $result["a"];
$existingB = $result["b"];

if(($existingA != $a) || ($existingB != $b)){
    run_query("UPDATE table SET a=$a, b=$b, Updateinfo='Timestamp+IP'");
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I misinterpreted OP's question

Comment: i think in this way you everytime update the updateinfo, mysql will alway sucess this if-part!?

Comment: I just copied what you had given, you can of course make the values dynamic.

Comment: yes of course ;-) but i think that is not the way to do what i want!?

Comment: If so, please edit your question so that we may understand it better. From what I understood, you will first update the `a` and `b`, then if they are successful, you will update `Updateinfo`, am I correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "change", changes in the value of `a` and `b` or after the updating the database with the values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: i mean if the current value of a or b is different to the existing value there should be a update in the database and then should be updated the updateinfo too

Comment: Check my Revise #1, like that?

Comment: yes but if i dont be at the wrong side, is that (in another way) the same think i already done. I check first the values as they are with a query and then i generate the update query. Is there no faster way without two querys to the db? If i have a lot of fields i think its not the finest way to do that!?

Answer (score 0):

here my solution in php style

`UPDATE software_config SET modifiedby=IF(STRCMP(main, '$main')=0 AND STRCMP(setting, '$setting')=0 AND STRCMP(value, '$value')=0, modifiedby, $new_value), main='$main', setting='$setting', value='$value' WHERE id=$id"`